# Express server crashes after MongoDB performs an operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm coding up a Node.js server using ExpressJS and MongoDB with MongooseJS.

I have a collection in which I want every document to live only for 24 hours. After that I want the DB to delete the document.

I have used two approaches - pure mongodb solution and using `mongoose-ttl` npm package.

Each of them work the same in my case - mongo makes a query that deletes the too old documents and right after that my ExpressJS server crashes with an error: `Error: socket hung up`.

The code for mongoose-ttl case:

```
const ttl = require('mongoose-ttl');

const weatherMeasurementsSchema = Schema({ parentRoomId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Room" }, temperature: Number, humidity: Number, createdAt: Date });

weatherMeasurementsSchema.plugin(ttl, { ttl: "1m", interval: "1m" });
```

The code for pure MongoDB case:

`db.measurements.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 60})`

For testing purposes I set the ttl and interval fields to 1 minute only, so I can gather the results earlier.

I have totally no idea what is wrong, is it something with DB connection? To connect to the db I use:

`mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1/wisehome", { useMongoClient: true });`

EDIT: I have gathered the error messages (identical for both cases):

```
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:253:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:345:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Comment: Are you able to use a local Mongo app with that exact same address (`mongodb://127.0.0.1/wisehome`)?

Comment: @Noah could you elaborate on what do you mean? I have multiple other endpoints that use the database and everything is fine. Only problem is with this mongodb document cleaning

Comment: Can you get us the log lines from Mongo server as TTL happens, in both cases?

Comment: @dilsingi Sure thing. Added it to the Edit section. Please check it out. This is a log from the Express server. While Im logged in with `mongo` command, no logs appear while it reaps the documents.

Comment: It looks the Express.js logs, I'm also looking for MongoDB server logs where we want to see what happens as it TTLs

Comment: @dilsingi should it appear in the terminal window after using `mongo` command? if so, then unfortunately Im not getting any logs there, only this one Ive posted above from express

Comment: Depends on installation if Linux be default /var/log/Mongodb/Mongodb.log. If it’s Mac /usr/local/var/mongodb.

Comment: @dilsingi Im using a Mac. Im in the folder, which file / directory in that folder exactly is that? Im really sorry for asking this, Im just beginning

Comment: It should be mongod.log

Comment: do `tail /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log `

Comment: Also try connect to mongo with an app like robomongo or mongohub.